# what picture size should I use when posting to FB feed via graph API?

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

I am using `https://graph.facebook.com/" + FB_id + "/feed` as the target for a post to publish to the feed of a user as described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ (search for "Publishing" section).

The picture parameter is described here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

But I was unable to find what is the recommended image size to be used when publishing like this.

I know the Image is displayed on both the user's own time-line and an hid friends' feeds and it would seem like they are differently sized in those two places.

So, What are the recommended picture dimensions when posting to Facebook Feed via the API Grpah ?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook recommends a photo size of at least 200px on a side, and an aspect ratio of no greater than 3:1. The maximum largest dimension for a photo is 960px.

Comment: That's no longer correct, since we use a 200x200 photo, and it gets cut on the sides on the mobile fb APP

Answer (score 0):

The current recommendation for optimizing images in the feed, including image size, are on the [Sharing Best Practices for Websites & Mobile Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images) documentation page.

> **Optimize your image sizes to generate great previews**
>
> Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels for the best display on
>   high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that
>   are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images.
>
> **Small Images**
>
> If your image is smaller than 600 x 315 px, it will still display in
>   the link page post, but the size will be much smaller.
>
> We've also redesigned link page posts so that the aspect ratio for
>   images is the same across desktop and mobile News Feed. Try to keep
>   your images as close to 1.91:1 aspect ratio as possible to display the
>   full image in News Feed without any cropping.
>
> **Game Apps Images**
>
> There are two different image sizes to use for game apps:
>
> Open Graph Stories Images appear in a square format. Image ratios for
>   these apps should be 600 x 600 px. Non-open Graph Stories Images
>   appear in a rectangular format. You should use a 1.91:1 image ratio,
>   such as 600 x 314 px.